# Replace activity content with static fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an app which is using an activity at the start. It is loading an xml-file to set the content at the onStart-procedure. After that the content is changed with a fragment which let the user make an input in an EditText view. This fragment is loaded dynamically at run time by using the FragmentManager and Transaction. Also on this fragment there is a Button to go on. When the user clicks the button another content is loaded at the onClick-procedure of that button. I tried to replace the first fragment with another one called “ListFrag.java” which is using a layout file called “list_frag.xml”. In portrait mode this new a simple xml-layout with some views on it.

The problem starts when the device is in landscape mode. I check this with “getResources().getConfiguration().orientation“.  At this time I would like to change the start fragment “ListFrag.java” with another version of the layout “list_frag.xml”.  Therefore I put this layout in a new res folder called “layout-land”. This layout defines a static fragment for the left pane and a frame-layout for the right pane. The frame-layout serves as a container for a detail fragmen to be loaded if the user clicked an item in the left pane.

I really do not know if it is possible to alter the content of an activity with a fragment on it using a layout with a static fragment definition in it. I tried already everything but nothing works. May be here someone has an idea.

Here are the source-code for the single files in the project. To shorten the code I removed the import-statements:
MainActivity:

```
package com.example.wbslideshow;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainFrag.onstartFragBtnClickListener {
    public static final String KEYVAL = "startpath"; 

    Bundle mySavedInstanceState;
    MainFrag newMainFrag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mySavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

        //initialize the preferences from the xml-file 
        //if app is running the first time this will be taken from the xml-file
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

        //load the MainFrag to select a path to the images and start-button
        newMainFrag = new MainFrag();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.mycontainer, newMainFrag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit(); 

    }

    //procedure from the interface of the MainFrag class to look for images in the given path
    @Override
    public void onstartFragBtnClicked(String root) 
    {
        //call procedure "private boolean LandscapeMode()" to check the mode
        if (!LandscapeMode())
        {
            ListFrag newListFrag = new ListFrag();
            //put the value from the EditText field of MainFrag class into the arguments for the ListFrag class
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ListFrag.FRAG_MESSAGE_DEF_Input, root);
            newListFrag.setArguments(args);

            //change the fragments dynamically
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mycontainer, newListFrag);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit(); 
        }
        else
        {
            //remove the MainFrag
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.remove(newMainFrag);
            transaction.commit(); 

            //load the static ListFrag 
            ListFrag newListFrag = new ListFrag();
            //put the value from the EditText field of MainFrag class into the arguments for the ListFrag class
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ListFrag.FRAG_MESSAGE_DEF_Input, root);

            //load the ImgFrag for the right pane into the FrameLayout 
            ImgFrag myImgFrag = new ImgFrag();
            if (myImgFrag != null) 
            {
                transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.myImgContainer, myImgFrag);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean LandscapeMode() { 
         if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==  
                   Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
             return false;
             }

         else 
             if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==  
               Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                 return true;
         } else return false;
    } 


}
```

MainFrag:
    package com.example.wbslideshow;

```
public class MainFrag extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{ //, OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    /*
     * Constant is representing the value of the android:key from preferences.xml. 
     * This value is found in android:defaultValue
    */
    public static final String KEYVAL = "startpath"; 
    public static final String JPGVAL = "pref-jpg";
    public static final String PNGVAL = "pref-png";

    EditText myEditText;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    //define the interface to communicate with the main activity when user clicked the button
    private onstartFragBtnClickListener mCallback;
    public interface onstartFragBtnClickListener {
        public void onstartFragBtnClicked(String myInput);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState ) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_frag, container, false);

        //instantiate the start button and register the onClickListener
        Button start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);

        //read the current path to the pics from SharedPreferences file
        Activity myActivity = getActivity();
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(myActivity.getBaseContext());

        //registerPreferenceListener();
        myEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearchPath);
        myEditText.setText(sharedPref.getString(KEYVAL, "/"));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //read the current path to the pics from SharedPreferences file
        Activity myActivity = getActivity();
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(myActivity.getBaseContext());
        myEditText.setText(sharedPref.getString(KEYVAL, "/"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach (Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {mCallback = (onstartFragBtnClickListener) activity;}
        catch (ClassCastException e) 
        {throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                  + " must implement OnControlButtonClickedListener");}
    }


    //change to ListFrag class if user clicked the button
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        Activity myActivity = getActivity();
        if (myActivity != null) 
        {
            //Get the users input for to pass it to the activity
            String root = ((EditText) myActivity.findViewById(
                    R.id.inputSearchPath)).getText().toString();

            //Call the interface method in the activity to go on
            mCallback.onstartFragBtnClicked(root);
        }
    }

}
```

ListFrag:

```
package com.example.wbslideshow;
public class ListFrag extends ListFragment{

    ImageView image;
    //Arrays to get files and folders 
    private List<String> listItem = null;
    //TextView  Object for the headline 
    private TextView TVmyPath;
    //global variable taken the start path once 
    //used to compare when user clicked an item
    private String g_startPath, g_myInput;

    /* define a constant to take the passed input string from the start fragment */
    public static String FRAG_MESSAGE_DEF_Input = "com.example.wbslideshow.CALL_ListFragment"; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState ) {
        View  myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frag, container, false);
        TVmyPath = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.startpath);
        return myview;
    } 

    @Override
    public void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();
        Activity myActivity = getActivity();

        //get an instance of the image and make it invisible 
        image = (ImageView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

         Bundle args = getArguments();
         if (args != null) { g_startPath = args.getString(FRAG_MESSAGE_DEF_Input); } 

         //save the input the very first time to compare later with new item click
         g_myInput = g_startPath;

         getDir(g_startPath);  
    }   

    private void getDir(String p_startPath)
    {
        //set the headline
        TVmyPath.setText("Location: " + p_startPath);

        listItem = new ArrayList<String>();

        File f = new File(p_startPath);
        //file array which get's all the folders and files from the input path
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        //startPath changed if user clicked a new folder 
        if(!g_myInput.equals(p_startPath))
        {
            //alter g_myInput for the next comparison
            g_myInput = p_startPath;
            //put this item to make it possible to get one directory up
            listItem.add("../");
        }

        Arrays.sort(files, filecomparator);

        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            if(files[i].isFile())
            {
                String filename = files[i].getName();
                //get the file extension 
                int z = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
                //read the file extension
                String wbname = filename.substring(z+1);
                if (wbname.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg"))  {listItem.add(filename);}
                if (wbname.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {listItem.add(filename);}
            }
            else {listItem.add(files[i].getName() + "/");}
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.row, listItem);
        Activity myActivity = getActivity();
        ListView myList = (ListView) myActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        myList.setAdapter(fileList); 
    }

    //procedure to sort the arrays
    Comparator<? super File> filecomparator = new Comparator<File>(){

        public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
            if(file1.isDirectory()){
                if (file2.isDirectory()){
                    return String.valueOf
                            (file1.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())).compareTo
                            (file2.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
                }else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }else {
                if (file2.isDirectory()){
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return String.valueOf
                            (file1.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())).compareTo
                            (file2.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
                }
            }
        }   
    };


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        File file;
        //user clicked one path back
        if (listItem.get(position) == "../") 
            {
                file = new File(g_startPath);
                g_startPath = file.getParent();
            }
        else 
        //if user clicked to a picture or 
        //to a new folder (>> getDir has to be called with the new path)
        //      >>file has to be set to path and position   
        {file = new File(g_startPath + '/' + listItem.get(position));}

            Bitmap myBitmap;
            //user clicked only to an image >> the image has to be shown in the image view - nothing else
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                //if(file.canRead()){
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
                image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //}
            }else   
            {
                if (file.isDirectory())
                {
                        image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        if (listItem.get(position) != "../"){g_startPath = file.getPath();}
                        getDir(g_startPath);
                }
            }   
    }
}
```

ImgFrag:

```
package com.example.wbslideshow;

public class ImgFrag extends Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View myImgView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_frag, container, false);
        return myImgView;
    }

}
```

The Layouts
activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DA8306"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/mycontainer">

</LinearLayout
```

main_frag.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FragMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/startHeader" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearchPath"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/startInputHint" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/startBtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout/list_frag.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listFrag"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startpath"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C27302"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="@string/list_header"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="312dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="#B012EB" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myImgContainer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout-land/list_frag.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- static fragment for the left pane -->
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.wbslideshow.ListFrag"
        android:id="@+id/listFrag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myImgContainer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

img_frag.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:id="@+id/imgFrag">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The code might not be perfect but this is not the issue here. In portrait-mode the app is working. Only in landscape mode i get a problem loading the listfrag. 
Here is also the current logcat:

> 10-11 13:20:12.563: W/dalvikvm(5158): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414539a8)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060041 (com.example.wbslideshow:id/myImgContainer) for fragment ImgFrag{417af140 #1 id=0x7f060041}
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:694)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   10-11 13:20:12.583: E/AndroidRuntime(5158):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I can see there is a problem with "no vie found ..." but I do not know why. For me it seems to be that the layout file from res/layout-land is not loaded in landscape mode and therefore the onCreateView for the IMgFrag gets a problem. 
But why?

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

ID `myImgContainer` is available in layout `layout-land/list_frag.xml`, by the time the click event is called, only `main_frag` will be shown on the screen, so instead of `R.id.myImgContainer` in MainActivity  user `R.id.mycontainer` itself.

Comment: Hi Dinash, many thanks for your answer. But tis did not work. If I follow your suggestion the LstFrag is not loaded when I change from portrait to landscape. If I start in landscape there is only a very small ImageView to be seen but no list. I think this could not work: Where should the static fragment go to and where should the ImageView go to if no id (ergo no container for it) is available?
Or may be I did not get your idea in the right way. Nevertheless any thanks so far
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `fragment` tag like that in the layout-land/list_frag.xml file.

list_frag.xml is the layout of your ListFrag class. You try to put ListFrag into it's own layout file. It's so wrong.

**Do you want a ImageView below a list in portrait mode and a ImageView to the right of the list (like two panels) when in landscape mode?**

If you want to do that. You just need to write your layout-land/list_frag.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listFrag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startpath"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="40dp"
            android:background="#C27302"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="@string/list_header"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="#B012EB" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You don't need the `myImgContainer`, so remove it from your layout/list_frag.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listFrag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startpath"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:background="#C27302"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="@string/list_header"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="312dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="#B012EB" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Change `onstartFragBtnClicked` method in `MainActivity`, only replace with the ListFrag. The platform will take care of which xml file to use as the ListFrag's layout.

```
public void onstartFragBtnClicked(String root) 
{
    ListFrag newListFrag = new ListFrag();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ListFrag.FRAG_MESSAGE_DEF_Input, root);
    newListFrag.setArguments(args);

    //change the fragments dynamically
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mycontainer, newListFrag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Feng Dai, nice approach and it works so far. But here are two things which I don't like:
- I have to touch twice the button to start ListFrag. Same with the Android return key. There might be a prob. with the backstack.
-For an App like I mentioned it would be ok. But what if there is another intention like having a right frag providing information for the left frag? A list is organizing the click to an item by it's own but I am interested in a solution with 2 frags for that situation. 
But you helped me already with the situation I described in my question - thanks!

Comment: Some additional thought: Would it be ok to call a fragment for the right side within the procedure "onOptionsItemSelected"? But I guess this is not very correct or? Sorry - but you see I am a little bit new to Android App programming!

Comment: Why you have to touch twice the button to start ListFrag? Any other information for the problem?

Comment: Read this article to see how to make a two panels UI with two fragments: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. With the double click it is difficult to say when it happens. As I mentioned above mostly if device is turned into another mode. But this is not so very much important for me - I will find it out later. The article you mentioned looks great. I will read it later and send you my feedback
Andreas

Comment: Hello, the article is very helpfull in many ways. Thank you for that. But my problem is a little bit different:main concern is to have one starting fragment

Comment: You can use nested fragment: Use a fragment to contain ListFrag and ImgFrag. That fragment has two layouts for portrait mode and landscape mode. It would be a little complicated in this situation. My question is: Dose it necessary to do this? What the benefits for you.

Comment: Hello - sounds interesting with nested frags. I will give it a try later. I am sure there are many ways to program this. I am a beginner with Apps. I read in Google Developer about the benefits of using frags (reusing code, easy information changing, one stable container for UI components, etc.). So I wanted to get used using frags from the beginning. May be I have to learn that this is not the all in one solution for every design. Many thanks so far - I will let you know. Andreas